# Placing script tag in div and execute

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I'm building a small advertisement system for my website so that I can just add new ads in the database. Most ads consists of images and I will just write an image as innerhtml to a div. This works fine.
However, some ads consists of a script tag only that should be placed where the ad is wanted. Since I have to do this dynamically from either code behind in .NET or from an ajax call, I have some problems with this.
Just setting a innerhtml of a div like this:

```
<div id="asdf" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="xxxxx"></script>
</div>
```

... won't work since it won't get executed. No matter if i set it in the code behind on page load, or set with an ajax call.

I might be able to call eval() somehow, but this doesn't guarantee the script will be placed exactly where i want it to be if I got it right.

Any ideas? This can't be a new problem, many advertising networks has script tags instead of images and such.

**Edit:** The javascript file is located on another domain. Everything works if i set the src attribute to a local file containing only an alert! Can't you make this happen across domains?

Comment: Am I to understand you're adding this data asynchronously, after the page is loaded?

Comment: Ive tried both this method and by doing it in the page load in the code behind. No matter what method, the script is added but not executed.

Comment: If setting `src` to a local file containing an alert works, something tells me the problem is in the third-party script. Is it maybe waiting for a `document.ready` which had already fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'xxxxxx';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
var div = document.getElementById('asdf');
div.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Well. I think the external script that I was trying to call either didn't work very well when called after page load, or some other strange error occured. The above code is what I used and it works well for other scripts. I will therefore mark this as the correct answer even though I didn't manage to resolve my issues. I had to work around them in a completely different way. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can add script tags dynamically, if you know from which source you want to add a file, like this:

```
    // Get head object from DOM.
var head_obj = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0);

// Create script object.
var script_obj  = document.createElement( 'script' );
script_obj.type = 'text/javascript';
script_obj.src  = File_Path;

// Define functions to be called on script load and load body.
script_obj.onload = onLoadFunc;

// Appendnd script object to the head object.
head_obj.appendChild( script_obj );
```

Hope that helps

Comment: But this adds the script to the head. I have to place it exactly where i want the ad.

Comment: Exactly for the reason that you want the script to get executed.